# When to send a post request using volley

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I have to send a post request to the api server when i exit the activity or when i go back to parent activity or even when someone abruptly closes the activity. How can i achieve it? Which lifecycle method among these would be best to achieve it.

```
onPause() 
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

The onPause() Method may not be the preferred way to do it since a activity can pause if for example at a moment when a call comes in since that would cause it to queue multiple post requests.

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write in onPause, but before calling API check your activity is finishing or not by using is isFinishing() method. Please read below url for further reference.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Silvans Solanki i guess that should do it.